# Efficient layouts creating

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I found out that for a "backend developer", who I am, creating layouts in XML is surprisingly time-consuming. Even for a simple app, arranging all the visual elements / widgets / whatever name you give them, number of things to do is quite large. I try to make this work faster by e.g. using almost always Linear Layouts (so that I don't have to determine arrangement of everything as in Relative Layout) and decrease things to be set, but still there are a lot details to determine, like setting a color, background, margins, padding - and these are just a basic ones - and the same routine task for all of the elements!

Using a visual disigner such as the one in the Android Studio is actually not an option for a serious app, where a dev needs to control of which type each element is, in particular Layout ViewGroups. Creating a layout in an old Java-style by writing a code is probably the worst possibility, as it breaks the MVC approach.

So I'd like to ask you: **are there some better, more efficient ways to work with layouts as being built by XML?**

*UPDATE*: To avoid possible misunderstandings, pleas note that I'm not asking about another way to create layouts than code or XML for Android. I'm asking about a method, trick, plugin or anything, that would make the job of *creating layouts in XML* faster.

Answer (score 0):

Android framework provides only two ways to create layout: XML and Java code.
If you have to set equal color, padding, margins etc. for more than one `View`, you should consider using [Styles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Simple layout usually looks simple in XML. If it is not the case, you probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, it "looks" simple. Android Studio even makes the work faster by including some obvious properties for elements. Yet, still I think that there must be an approach, plugin or anything, which could make this job to be faster. E.g. like having a pre-defined set of auto-included properties (this is what I'm thinking about).

Comment: @forsberg You can use a style for that. Style can contain any properties (including `layout_width` and `layout_height`). I can't imagine anything simpler than `<TextView style="TitleText" />`.